# VHDL JK Flip-Flop with logic gates

Tags: vhdl

I am trying to make a JK flip-flop in ActiveHDL environment.
**I want to make it with logic gates.**

It should look like this:

[image]

This is my code:

```
--nand3.vhd
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity nand3 is 
    port(
    A,B,C: in std_logic;
    D: out std_logic
    );
end entity;

architecture nand3 of nand3 is 
begin
    D <= not(A and B and C);
end architecture;
```

```
--nand2.vhd
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity nand2 is 
    port(
    A,B: in std_logic;
    C: out std_logic
    );
end entity;

architecture nand2 of nand2 is 
begin
    C <= not (A and B);
end architecture;
```

```
--JK.vhd
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity JK is 
    port(
    J,K: in std_logic;
    Q, NQ: out std_logic;
    CLK: in std_logic
    );
end entity;

architecture JK of JK is
component nand3 
    port(
    A,B,C: in std_logic;
    D: out std_logic
    );
end component;

component nand2
    port(
    A,B: in std_logic;
    C: out std_logic
    );
end component;  

signal s1, s2: std_logic;

begin
    C11: nand3 port map(NQ,J,CLK,S1);
    C12: nand3 port map(Q,K,CLK,S2);
    C21: nand2 port map(S1,NQ,Q);
    C22: nand2 port map(S2,Q,NQ);
end architecture;
```

The problem is that i am getting this error when I compile `JK.vhd` file:

```
# Error: COMP96_0411: JK.vhd : (31, 22): Actual of mode "out" can not be assigned to formal "A" of mode "in"
# Error: COMP96_0411: JK.vhd : (32, 22): Actual of mode "out" can not be assigned to formal "A" of mode "in"
# Error: COMP96_0411: JK.vhd : (33, 25): Actual of mode "out" can not be assigned to formal "B" of mode "in"
# Error: COMP96_0411: JK.vhd : (34, 25): Actual of mode "out" can not be assigned to formal "B" of mode "in"
```

I think the problem is the backward signals.